# Properly Formatting Set Output in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program who's input is a set of sets (or "collection") in python syntax. The output of the program should be the  same collection in proper mathematical syntax. To do so, I've written a recursive function

```
collection = set([
            frozenset(["a,b,c"]),
            frozenset(),
            frozenset(["a"]),
            frozenset(["b"]),
            frozenset(["a,b"])
            ])

def format_set(given_set):
    # for each element of the set
    for i in given_set:
        #if the element is itself a set, begin recursion
        if type(i) == frozenset:
            format_set(i)
        else:
            return "{", i, "},",
```

calling `format_set(collection)` gives the output

```
{ a,b }, { a,b,c }, { b }, { a },
```

which is missing a pair of parenthesis, and has an extra comma at the end. The correct output would be

```
{{ a,b }, { a,b,c }, { b }, { a },{}}.
```

Thus, I would need to add "{" before the first recursion, and "}" after the last, as well as not adding the comma after the last recursion. Is there a way to find the final recursion?

I could always solve the extra parenthesis problem by defining:

```
def shortcut(x):
    print "{", frozen_set(x), "}"
```

However, I feel like that's somewhat inelegant, and still leaves the comma problem.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: is it possible to find the last recursion? If not, how do I get rid of the extra comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be more straightforward if you check the type first and then do the iteration:

```
def format_set(given):
    if isinstance(given, (set, frozenset)):
        return '{' + ', '.join(format_set(i) for i in given) + '}'
    else:
        return str(given)
```

Output:

```
{{a,b}, {a,b,c}, {}, {b}, {a}}
```

---

Also, note that in your example input all sets are actually empty or have 1 element. If you change the input like this...

```
collection = set([
            frozenset(["a", "b", "c"]),
            frozenset(),
            frozenset(["a"]),
            frozenset(["b"]),
            frozenset(["a", "b"])
            ])
```

...you'll get this output:

```
{{a, c, b}, {}, {b}, {a}, {a, b}}
```

Comment: Good call on using `join` ;)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain this line:

 (format_set(i) for i in given if i)? 

How does this construct an iterable for join, and what is the "if i" for? Is there a name for this kind of syntax/expression?

Comment: @EvanRosica The argument of `join` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). If you are new to Python, you might want to start with looking up _list comprehensions_ first, then read up on generators, and then generator expressions will be easy to understand. The `if i` is there because your desired output doesn't have the empty set. Comprehensions can have an optional `if` clause with any expression after the `if`, but you can omit it and see what happens.

Comment: The correct output should contain the empty set. That was an error on my part. I edited the question and the answer (by removing the if i) to reflect this.